# why my app_name show as plural by s by navigation into URL link? [login]

Tags: python, django

when I do submit this form why has been submitted by accounts/profile? I've no any file called accounts basically. my app_name calls account not accounts.
so, How can I submit my form according to app_name that I using 
**[Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu7J4.png)**

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, logout

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    # /account/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="home"),
    # /account/login/
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='account/login.html'), name='login_page'),
    # /account/logout/
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name': 'account/logout.html'}, name='logout'),
    # /account/register/
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    # /account/profile/
    url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
    # /account/profile/edit/
    url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    # /account/profile/edit/
    url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
]
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Login {% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I've no more files to explain that
I think these files just show you what happens when logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide **[LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)**.

If **LoginView** called via POST with user submitted credentials, it tries to log the user in. If login is successful, the view redirects to the URL specified in next. If next isn’t provided, it redirects to [settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL) (which defaults to /accounts/profile/). If login isn’t successful, it redisplays the login form. See [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views)